# Resize svg object with mouse on svg,js 3.x

Tags: svg.js

i'm using svg.js to load external svg file and then add some element on the svg.
I need to permit the user to place some shape on the svg and then drag and resize it.
I cannot find any plugin/code to allow the user to resize a shape for svg.js 3.1
How can i do that?